# Node transform stream not waiting

Tags: node.js, busboy

I'm getting a file stream from Busboy and then i'm piping it to a custom transform stream to validate and clean it. It works with small files but as they get bigger my custom stream doesn't wait for the busboy stream to finish and it gets truncated.

Here is the busboy code:

```
busboy
.on("file", function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
    //Creating a mongo doc first
    Dataset.create(dataset, function (err, ds) {
        if(err) {...} 
        else {
            file.pipe(validateCSV));
        }
    });

    validateCSV
        .on("finish", function() {
            // Send to Data Import
            datasetService.import(validateCSV, dataset, function (err, result) {
                ...
            });
        });
});
```

And my transform stream:

```
module.exports.ValidateCSV = ValidateCSV;
function ValidateCSV(options) {
    if (!(this instanceof ValidateCSV)) return new ValidateCSV(options);

    if (!options) options = {};
    options.objectMode = true;
    Transform.call(this, options);
}

util.inherits(ValidateCSV, Transform);

ValidateCSV.prototype._transform = function (chunk, encoding, done) {
    if (this._checked) {
        this.push(chunk);
    } else {
        //Do some validation
        var data = chunk.toString();
        var lines = data.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
        var headerline = lines[0] || "";
        var header = headerline.split(",");
        ...
        this._checked = true;
        this.push(chunk);
    }
    done()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out it was a backpressure issue and seeting the HighWaterMark option on the transform stream fixed it. Ideally it woold be set according to the filesize of the upload but this fixed it for me:

```
function ValidateCSV(options) {
    if (!(this instanceof ValidateCSV)) return new ValidateCSV(options);

    if (!options) options = {};
    options.objectMode = true;
    options.highWaterMark = 100000;
    Transform.call(this, options);
}
```